# how can I use multiple vlookup criteria in excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a problem with `vlookup` using multiple criteria. I have a sheet with my model, sheet with my parameters and sheet with lapses.

In sheets model I'am using `vlookup` function as follows:

```
VLOOKUP(Parameters_new!$C$3&"|"&H16;CHOOSE({1,2};lapses_monthly_2018!$B:$B&"|"&lapses_monthly_2018!$C:$C;lapses_monthly_2018!$D:$D);2;0)
```

where:
`Parameters_new!$C$3` is code of my product, `column H16` is month from the start (1,2,3....), `lapses_monthly_2018!$B:$B` is another different sheet, where in column B is my product, `column C` is the month and in `column D` is my final value, I´m trying to get. I always get a value "not available".

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
{=INDEX(lapses_monthly_2018!$D:$D,MATCH(1,(lapses_monthly_2018!$B:$B=Parameters_new!$C$3)*(lapses_monthly_2018!$C:$C=$H$16),0),1,1)}
```

Be aware - this is an array formula, so to get the curly brackets to show and initiate the array, you must execute the formula with control&shift&enter